# How to hide the android keyboard when switching tabs/activities?

Tags: android, keyboard, hide

I been searching for a good solution to the problem here on stackoverflow, since it is a commonly asked question. Some people claim that just by putting

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` 
or 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` 
in your androidmanifest activity, it will hide the keyboard. But it does not for me. In my app I use 5 tabs(activities) and one of them is a search tab.

In my search function I have implemented:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

which works great if you click on the search button in the search tab(activity). But if you click on the edittext and then switch to another tab the keyboard follows and does not disappear. How can I remove the keyboard when switching tabs?

Comment: oh, I will, missed that one totally. I am pretty new on the site

Comment: @user1293618 See [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ for some good info about how the hole system works.